# PHP Header location trim or empty

Tags: php

php

```
<?php
     header('Location: '.urldecode($_GET['url']));
     exit();
?>
```

How can I get it redirect to index page (mydomain.com) when there is no url or someone trim the url in this way:

1. mydomain.com/go.php/?url=
2. mydomain.com/go.php

Thanks in advance.

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: Hello @MarcB thanks sir. but i still have to find out the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
    $domain = explode(".php/?", $url);

    header('Location: '.$domain.".php");
    exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statement as @Marc B said in a comment.

```
$url = (isset($_GET['url']) && !empty($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : NULL;
if(empty($url)){
   header('Location: http://www.mydoamin.com');
   exit();
}
//the other code you want to execute if the url if set and not empty.
```

1- [isset](https://www.php.net/isset) to check if the parameter `url` is set.

2- [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if the paremeter `url` is empty.

3- [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary)
Conditional operator is the "?:" (or ternary) operator.